# Struts2 rest webservice with hibernate entity issue

Tags: hibernate, rest, struts2

I am doing webservice with Struts2 rest plugin, i am able to send normal text and object as json response, but if i try to send Hibernate entity which is having relationships I am not able to send as json response it is giving error as

```
No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: 
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException["path"]->java.util.UnmodifiableList[0]->org.codehaus.jackson.map.Reference["from"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->app.com.gmf.DTO.RestaurantMasterBean["resType"]->app.com.gmf.DTO.RestaurantTypeBean_$$_javassist_4["hibernateLazyInitializer"])
```

Comment: How did you use Struts2 rest plugin?

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all : `JsonMappingException`

The bean you're trying to send contains other objects and is not fetched eagerly & hence, there are properties which are not initialized. When the bean is marshalled to JSON, these properties fail. There are multiple solutions :

1. Fetch EAGER (not recommended)
2. Send only the properties you need and make sure they're fetched before returning from action, otherwise you might get a `LazyInitializationException` wrapped within `JsonMappingException`. As said it appears from the question, that `jackson` is being used, then you can do something like :

Example :

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"resType"})
public class RestaurantMasterBean{
private SomeOtherObject resType;
private String name;
private boolean shouldInform;

// getter and setters here...
}
```

3. Simply ignore the lazy fields like :

`@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer"})`